# Assign values of array from for loop java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I'm still a newbie in Java. 
What I want to do here is to assign the values from the for loop into an array.

Here is a hardcoded example of what I wanted to achieve:

```
public class Nodes {
private int noOfNodes;
private Points[] points;

Nodes(){

}

Nodes(int noOfNodes){
    this.noOfNodes = noOfNodes;

Points[] points = {
        new Points("A", 100, 200),
        new Points("B", 200, 300),
        new Points("C", 300, 400),
        new Points("D", 650, 650),
        new Points("E", 500 , 600)
    };

this.points=points;        
}
```

The code that I'm trying to append the values from the loop:

```
Points [] points = new Points[this.noOfNodes];
       for(int i=0; i<noOfNodes-(noOfNodes-1); i++){
           //randomly generate x and y
           float max = 1000;
           float min = 1;
           float range = max - min + 1;

           for (int j=0; j<noOfNodes; j++){

               String name = Integer.toString(noOfNodes);
               float x = (float)(Math.random() * range) + min;
               float y = (float)(Math.random() * range) + min;

           }
       }
    this.points=points;
}
```

I would love to achieve the same output but I'm not getting the values from the for loop array inside points. Any help is appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Comment: So what is the point of `i<noOfNodes-(noOfNodes-1)` this is always `1` so why have a loop at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few mistakes in your code. You're using floats instead of integers, which doesn't make sense here, you're not assigning any values to your `points` array, and that outer for-loop is useless, since it will run exactly once, because your condition is `i < noOfNodes - (noOfNodes - 1)`, which is the same as `i < 1`.

Here is one way to fill that array up with randomly generated values.

```
//outside your constructor
private static final int max = 1000, min = 1;

//in your constructor
this.points = new Points[noOfNodes];

for (int i = 0; i < noOfNodes; i ++) {
  points[i] = new Point(Character.toString(i + 'A'), (int) (Math.random() * max) - min, (int) (Math.random() * max) - min);
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for your explanation, sir.